# Does KDE Neon use Ubunu LTS point releases?

Tags: ubuntu, kernel, kde-neon, lts

The KDE Neon [FAQ](https://neon.kde.org/faq) mentions it's build on Ubuntu LTS 18.04. It doesn't mention which point release of Ubuntu LTS it's using.

I would like to try out KDE Neon, but I know my laptop doesn't work well (or at all) on kernel versions before 4.19. Default LTS comes with kernel 4.5 and is not an option. According to the [Ubuntu kernel overview](https://ubuntu.com/about/release-cycle#ubuntu-kernel-release-cycle), Ubuntu 18.04.3 would be the first version that would work for me.

1. Does KDE Neon follow Ubuntu point releases?
2. Alternatively, is it possible to manually enable the HWE as described on the [Ubuntu wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack#Ubuntu_18.04_LTS_-_Bionic_Beaver)? With:

   sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-hwe-18.04

Or would that break the KDE Neon [update](https://neon.kde.org/faq#command-to-update) system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the requisite information by visiting https://files.kde.org/neon/images/user/current/.

In particular, https://files.kde.org/neon/images/user/current/neon-user-20200213-1120.manifest has

```
linux-generic-hwe-18.04 5.3.0.28.96
linux-headers-5.3.0-28  5.3.0-28.30~18.04.1
linux-headers-5.3.0-28-generic  5.3.0-28.30~18.04.1
linux-headers-generic-hwe-18.04 5.3.0.28.96
linux-image-5.3.0-28-generic    5.3.0-28.30~18.04.1
linux-image-generic-hwe-18.04   5.3.0.28.96
linux-modules-5.3.0-28-generic  5.3.0-28.30~18.04.1
linux-modules-extra-5.3.0-28-generic    5.3.0-28.30~18.04.1
linux-signed-generic-hwe-18.04  5.3.0.28.96
```

In other words, you could use https://files.kde.org/neon/images/user/current/neon-user-current.iso.